# row sum on a pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am stuck on trying to figure out how to add a row sum to a pandas pivot table. Would somebody please help point me towards the right direction.

This is my code below.

```
x.pivot_table(index = ["am","spot_or_contract"],
              columns = "status",
              values = "shipment_id",
              aggfunc = "count").fillna('')
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Could you provide some example data?

Comment: How would you do this for each individual grouping?  So a sum the number of "shipment_id" for each "am"/"spot_or_contract" group

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Look at `margins` parameter in pivot_table:

```
x.pivot_table(index = ["am","spot_or_contract"], 
              columns = "status" , 
              values = "shipment_id", 
              aggfunc = "count",
              margins = True,
              fill_value = "")
```